# actualizar fila de tabla HTML dinamica

Tags: jquery, html

Buen día, tengo un formulario con seis campos de texto en los que el usuario digita información y al presionar el botón submit estos se agregan de manera dinámica una tabla HTML, solo los muestro en la tabla, no hay nada de ingresos en la base de datos, eso lo manejo después y de momento todo trabaja bien, este es el código del formulario y la tabla

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="inputText1" required>
        <input type="text" id="inputText2" required>
        <input type="text" id="inputText3" required>
        <input type="text" id="inputText4" required>
        <input type="text" id="inputText5" required>
        <input type="text" id="inputText6" required>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="actualizar">Actualizar</button>


    <br /><br />
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" id="myTable" style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Nivel</th>
                    <th>DUI</th>
                    <th>ISSS</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

- Actualizar datos de fila de tabla HTML

Pero ahora viene la parte de actualizar cualquier fila de la tabla -por petición- se ha agregado un botón select a cada fila de la tabla el cual al presionarse coloca la información de cada columna de la fila seleccionada en el campo de texto correspondiente con este código:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#myTable").on('click', '#select', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

             var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); 
             var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); 
             var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); 
             var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text(); 
             var col5 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text(); 
             var col6 = currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text(); 

             $("#inputText1").val(col1);
             $("#inputText2").val(col2);
             $("#inputText3").val(col3);
             $("#inputText4").val(col4);
             $("#inputText5").val(col5);
             $("#inputText6").val(col6);

             $(this).closest('tr').remove();

        });
    });
```

y si me muestra la información en los campos de texto, el problema es que no sé cómo actualizar la información de exactamente la fila seleccionada, de momento lo que hago es:

1. Eliminar la fila seleccionada que el usuario desea modificar de la
   tabla y mostrar la información de cada celda en los campos de texto correspondientes.
2. EL usuario modifica cualquier información desde los campos de texto
3. y el usuario al dar click al botón modificar agrega la información
   de cada campo de texto como una nueva fila, la fila anterior ha
   desaparecido

pero quisiera que no desapareciera de la tabla, quisiera que se poblaran los campos de texto pero que la fila permanezca en la tabla y que al momento de actualizar se me actualice la fila correspondiente

¿cómo podría lograrlo?

Les recuerdo que estas operaciones no representan ninguna conexión a la base de datos, gracias por la ayuda.

la tabla la cargo tomando los valores de los inputs y luego realizando un append sobre la tabla y luego limpio los valores de cada input, de la siguiente manera:

```
var dui = $("#inputText1").val();
                var lastname = $("#inputText2").val();
                var name = $("#inputText3").val();
                var country = $("#inputText4").val();
                var DUI = $("#inputText5").val();
                var ISSS = $("#inputText6").val();

 $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr><td for="dui">' + dui + '</td><td for="lastname">' + lastname + '</td><td for="name">' + name + '</td><td>' + country + '</td><td for="DUI">' + DUI + '</td><td for="ISSS">' + ISSS + '</td><td><a href="#" id="select">Modificar</a></td></tr>');
                        $("#inputText1").val('');
                        $("#inputText2").val('');
                        $("#inputText3").val('');
                        $("#inputText4").val('');
                        $("#inputText5").val('');
                        $("#inputText6").val('');
                        $('#inputText1').focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloca un id a tu tabla y un onclick a cada boton cuando se ingrese de forma dinamica, a traves de un arreglo, para poder establecer que fila es la que estas obteniendo los datos, y saber donde debes almacenarlos. Para ello una vez que hagas click en uno de estos botones, debes almacenar esto en una variable oculta.

```
TABLA = IDTABLA
COL1 COL2 COL3 BOTON
 X1   X4   X7  onclick=1
 X2   X5   X8  onclick=2
 X3   X6   X9  onclick=3

<table id="IDTABLA">
    <tr>
        <th>COL1</th>
        <th>COL2</th>
        <th>COL3</th>
        <th>BOTON</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>X1</td>
        <td>X4</td>
        <td>X7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>X2</td>
        <td>X5</td>
        <td>X8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>X3</td>
        <td>X6</td>
        <td>X9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button onclick="modificando(1)">Actualizar</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="modificando(2)">Actualizar</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="modificando(3)">Actualizar</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Y colocaremos un script que al pinchar cualquier actualizar llamara a este pasandole el numero que hemos definido al hacer la tabla. Y este le pasara a la variable oculta que hemos dicho (input)

```
<script>
    function modificando(numero){
        $("#variableModificando").val(numero);
        //Crear el insertado a los respectivos inputs
    }
</script>
```

guardar en `<input type="text" id="variableModificando" hidden="true" value="2">`

Asi te capturara

```
<input type="text" id="COL1" value="X2">
<input type="text" id="COL2" value="X5">
<input type="text" id="COL3" value="X8">
```

Y los nuevos valores que actualizaremos seran a

```
<input type="text" id="COL1" value="Y1">
<input type="text" id="COL2" value="Y2">
<input type="text" id="COL3" value="Y3">
```

Para capturar los datos, cuando presiones modificar, este vaya al siguiente script

```
tabla = document.getElementById("IDTABLA");
        fila = $("#variableModificando").val();
        for (var i = 0; i >= 3; i++) {
            tabla.rows[fila].cells[i].innerText = $("#COL"+i).val();
        }
```

Donde se le va actualizando el DOM de a una columna por su identificador.
Y debiese quedar como esperas

```
TABLA = IDTABLA
COL1 COL2 COL3 BOTON
X1   X4   X7  onclick=1
Y1   Y2   Y3  onclick=2
X3   X6   X9  onclick=3
```

Espero que te ayude :D

Answer (score 0):

Cuando agregues una fila a tu tabla ponle un id a tu tr y un name a tu boton con el id también, este id puede ser el id de tus datos con esto se te simplifica la selección con JQuery.

no se como agregas los datos a la tabla, podría ser útil que también nos digas eso.Pero si tu fila esta asi  lo unico que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
     $("#myTable").on('click', '#select', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var idbutton=$(this).name;
         var currentRow = $("td#"+idbutton);

         $("#inputText1").val(currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text() );
         $("#inputText2").val(currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text() );
         $("#inputText3").val(currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text() );
         $("#inputText4").val(currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text() );
         $("#inputText5").val(currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text() );
         $("#inputText6").val(currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text() );
    });
});
```

Comment: hola, perdón la demora, he actualizado la pregunta para mostrar como agrego los datos a la tabla, talvez puedas ayudarme.